# How can I add a new button to the navigation pane (outlook bar) in Outlook 2003/2007?

Tags: c++, windows, com, plugins, outlook

Most of us are familiar with the "accordion-style" navigation bar on the left side of Outlook 2003.  It has buttons like Calendar, Tasks, Mail, etc, and clicking on one of those buttons opens up a browser pane with the list of common folders in that section.

Using C++ or Delphi, I'd like to write a plugin that adds a new section to the navigation pane.  Does anyone know where to start?

I found a few postings using google that say things like, "It's impossible but if you get add-in express then it's possible" (eg. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/a3517364-b1af-4583-966a-61717afa1028/), which sounds to me like it's possible, not impossible :)  Where do I look?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This site have info for you :

http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36

Good look.

Comment: All posts on this site just say you can't do it.. that's not helpful.. like the question owner said.. add-in express can do it, so it IS possible, but how is done?